# Atualização do Python em Debian

Tags: python, linux

Minha máquina roda o Debian 9 e queria atualizar o Python para a última versão sem modificar a versão do Debian.

É possível fazer isso através de algum repositório oficial ou terei que instalar manualmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode instalar manualmente por meio de um canal oficial.

Segue o link para atualização do python3.7 para o python3.8 no debian 10.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-debian-10/

Pessoalmente não recomendo atualização de pacotes importantes para o sistema como o Python. O ideal é que você instalasse o Python mais recente e continuasse utilizando o Python do seu sistema como padrão, usando o Python mais recente apenas quando necessário.